# Displaying only favorite tags on homepage

Tags: support, tags, bookmarks, filtering, tag-watching

Hello everybody,

is there a way to see on the homepage only the questions that match the favorite tags ?
i've searched in the question history, but seems i can only use multiple tags in the url with OR, AND logic but nothing automatic for all of my favorite tags.

thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that the option I have is to use the stackexchange favorite-tag filter inside "My Filter".

https://stackexchange.com/filters

Comment: How can I use this for stackoverflow? the `/filters` url doesn't work for SO. I would like to filter be automatically adjusted for my current favorite tags without the need to update the filter manually.

Answer (score 5):

The home page already kind of works this way, assuming you are logged in and have favorite tags set up.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/

Comment: my favorite tags does not include any of the tags I see in the homepage, am i missing something?  if i go to the SO homepage or the "questions" section i see all the questions, not only those that matches my favorite tags.

Comment: @alor did you read the blog post? Please read it, it contains the answer to your question.

Comment: ok, understood the formula. but I prefer the SE "My Filter" to just see the relevant tags, really don't want to see questions outside my competence or interests.  thank you.

Comment: @alor sure, the "My Filter" is fine as well http://stackexchange.com/filters -- whatever works!

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

### Show "unanswered" questions in your tags

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags

### Show all questions in your tags

Use intags:mine operator

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine