# StackOverflow homepage to show only questions from my favourite tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-watching, homepage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Displaying only favorite tags on homepage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83787/displaying-only-favorite-tags-on-homepage)

Can I configure StackOverflow's Homepage to show only questions from my `favourite tags` ?

Say I have added these 4 tags as my favourite tags

- asp.net-mvc
- asp.net-mvc2
- asp.net-mvc3
- asp.net

and I only want to see questions from these tags on my homepage, is this possible ?

I have added the above tags to my favourite, still I get questions from other tags(Which I really cant relate to)

Please some one help me on this

Comment: Go to the [interesting tags tab](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/).

Comment: Also see [Option to set a tag as default for first opening page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138479/138496#138496)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but you can create a filter for the tags on [stackexchange.com/filters](https://stackexchange.com/filters), and browse the filter page instead of Stack Overflow's homepage.

I've created a [filter for you](https://stackexchange.com/filters/54252/asp-net), using all four tags, but you should go ahead and create your own.

Comment: yes, that exactly what I want. Thanks @Yannis

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine will list the questions tagged with any one of ur fav. tags